# How to add master-detail navigation system to an existing iPhone storyboard?

Tags: ios5, storyboard, master-detail, xcode4.6

I have an application with a navigation controller and a few views, but now I need to add master-detail view mechanism to one of my view controllers. I am using storyboards. How can I implememt such functionality without reinventing the wheel? I've searched the web but all I've found was examples with creating apps as master-detail apps from scratch, I haven't found an example of adding it to an already existing app.

Thank you,

Can.

Comment: are you still in need of help?

Comment: well, i've used a workaround (JTRevealSidebar) and it worked for my case, but if you've got anything that would enable to implement a true master/detail controller, i'd be (and future askers of this question) glad to learn it :)

Comment: I'm glad you have a solution.  I guess I'm not totally sure what you mean when you say "true" master/detail.  Typically that is two (or more) scenes that work together to "dig" into more detail from one item or object.  Example, the master page shows a list of photos and the detail view shows only the photo selected and maybe allows some editing controls.  A reveal control can be used in a master detail type way, but more generally they represent a type of navigation and are used many different ways.  There are a number of good "reveal" controls available.

Comment: there are controls, and master-detail template is just a "template", but i'm really wondering if it's possible to "add it into" an existing project if not selected in the beginning..

Comment: I may not be understanding you completely but basically you just and two viewControllers in your app.  Setup the first to do the "master" stuff, create a transition to the other via push or modal and have the other do the "detail" work.  for example- view controller 1 presents a table of items. view controller two presents all the detail from a single item, selected from the first.  Apple does not have a control to drop in - you just add the views yourself, configure and connect them.  now if you want one to hide behind the other you may need something like a reveal control.

Comment: thanks, I'll be investigating the issue further in detail soon..